# Window Shutters covering doorbell

Tags: electrical, doorbell, shutters

My wife would like to install decorative window shutters on the window next to the front door. This type of shutter is simply bolted into the wall, and won't be able to move after installation.

The problem is that the shutters are wide enough that they would cover up the doorbell. My wife is of the opinion that we don't need the doorbell anyway and is fine with the shutter blocking the doorbell. But, my feeling is that this would probably be a bad idea.

Is this a reason for concern? Would I be better off paying to have the doorbell resituated?

Comment: I don't know why you'd pay someone to move a doorbell. You're on a DIY site, which implies that you have some interest and aptitude for DIY. It's not usually difficult and you could also switch to a wireless model. That said, your question is a matter of opinion (and therefore off topic here). There are no doorbell codes. Good luck.

Comment: why us a covered door bell a problem? ... you would still hear it

Comment: Think he means doorbell button, not the doorbell itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paint a length of 1x3 wood to match the wall. Choose a piece long enough to cover the old button location and reach your new location. Cut a groove on the back of the wood piece for the wire extension to go from old to new. Wire up the new button, then connect the 2 wires to the original button location. It is usually 16 volts ac, you can turn off the power if you choose. The mounting screws for the wood piece can be hidden behind the shutter and even behind the new button.

Answer (score 2):

Per @JohnCanon, cover up the old door bell, but instead of spending time and effort putting it in a new location, get a [wireless doorbell](https://www.amazon.com/wireless-doorbell/s?k=wireless+doorbell) ($10 to $30).

Or if you want, put on an old-school door knocker and call it a day.

Nowadays, people you know will call you on your cell phone. The door bell is a relatively low priority.